# Diff current file version and previous one remote repository

Tags: git, diff

How do I diff my working file version vs. some previous version in the remote repository?

Say, I pull today, perform 6 - 8 commits to my local copy and then want to see the diff between my latest working version ( of a given file ) and the latest on the remote or any other version.

Comment: Which revision control s/ware are u using. e.g. Subversion, TeamCity, etc. Then what is the IDE your using?

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're asking. You would do this exactly as you expect, by passing `origin/whatever` or a commit ID to `git diff`.

Comment: @meagar You're right, see the update.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're talking about a remote branch, say, `origin/master`, you can use `~` and `^` to refer to ancestor commits relative to a branch the same way you can with local branches:

```
# what change was introduced to origin/master in the last 4 commits?
git diff origin/master origin/master~3
```

If you want to diff your current working directory against the 5th most recent commit on `origin/master`, you would omit the first argument:

```
git diff origin/master~4
```

Comment: What's the difference between `~` and `^` ?

Comment: @OscarRyz ^ is the previous commit, ~ is always followed by an integer and means "go back x commits", so ^^^ is equal to ~3

Comment: @ganders No, that is not the chief difference. `^` is for navigating merge commits and choosing a parent, for navigating horizontally. `~` always proceeds backwards along the first parent path, for navigating vertically. You would be just as likely to use a number with `^` as with `~`, except where `~2` says "two commits ago", `^2` says "the second parent of the given commit".

Comment: @meagar thanks, I actually just found out I was wrong after going through this Git tutorial http://pcottle.github.io/learnGitBranching/?DEMO

Answer (score 13):

To see the diff between your 'latest working version' (I'll take that as your working copy) use:

```
git diff <remote>/<branch>
```

If you think somebody else has pushed to the remote then you need to fetch the changes:

```
git fetch <remote> <branch>
git diff <remote>/<branch>
```

If you want to restrict the diff to just a file or to all files in a directory use:

```
git diff <remote>/<branch> -- /path/to/file
git diff <remote>/<branch> -- /path/to/           #all files in directory
```

You can use `git difftool ...` to start a visual diff tool (assuming one exists on your machine).

Answer (score 3):

Suppose `path/to/file.txt` is some file that's committed to the remote branch `origin/master` and is also in my workspace, committed to the local branch `my-branch`.

Difference between the latest version of `path/to/file.txt` committed the remote branch and the (possibly uncommitted) version in my workspace:

```
git diff origin/master:path/to/file.txt path/to/file.txt
```

Difference between the version of `path/to/file.txt` committed the remote branch three commits ago and the (possibly uncommitted) version in my workspace:

```
git diff origin/master~3:path/to/file.txt path/to/file.txt
```

Difference between the latest version of `path/to/file.txt` committed the remote branch and the latest version committed to `my-branch`:

```
git diff origin/master:path/to/file.txt my-branch:path/to/file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
git fetch;  #this will attach the remote branch commits to your local tree
git diff FETCH_HEAD    #diff your working dir version of my_file vs the remote tip

same as
git diff remotes/origin/branch
```

But you must do a git-fetch first or you won't have the remote's commits locally available to diff against