# What's the difference between ~ and ^ in git

Tags: git

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10627431/20654) question long ago but I still don't know what do ~ and ^ mean in this answer:

> If you're talking about a remote branch, say, origin/master, you can
>   use ~ and ^ to refer to ancestor commits relative to a branch the same
>   way you can with local branches

What's the difference?

Comment: [Why not Zoidberg? (I mean, the manpage!)](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`^` means "(first) parent of". `~` is similar, but it takes a number as an argument and basically means "ancestor of". So, for example:

```
HEAD            = latest commit
HEAD^  = HEAD~1 = parent of latest commit
HEAD^^ = HEAD~2 = grandparent of latest commit
HEAD~100        = 100th ancestor of latest commit
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning the meaning of identifiers such as HEAD^2, which is different (the second parent's commit, where there is more than one parent).

Answer (score 5):

According to [this document](http://paulboxley.com/blog/2011/06/git-caret-and-tilde), tilde (~) references the linear ancestors of the commit (parent, grandparent, great-grandparent), whereas caret (^) references multiple parents.  In cases where there are multiple merge ancestors, each merge source would be a parent.

Comment: This answer is correct. The "accepted" answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

As [the manpage](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions.html) states:

> **`<rev>^, e.g. HEAD^, v1.5.1^0`** 
>       A suffix ^ to a revision parameter means the first parent of that commit object. `^<n>` means the `<n>`th parent (i.e. `<rev>^` is equivalent to `<rev>^1`). [...]
>
> **`<rev>~<n>, e.g. master~3`**
>       A suffix `~<n>` to a revision parameter means the commit object that is the `<n>`th generation ancestor of the named commit object, following only the first parents. I.e. `<rev>~3` is equivalent to `<rev>^^^` which is equivalent to `<rev>^1^1^1`.